# Have problems installing mod_python

Tags: django, apache, deployment, apache2, mod-python

I seem to have some problems installing mod_python with apache.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2
make
make install
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

On the final line, I seem to get this error.

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Actually there are two errors. I think we could get rid of `make_sock` by committing out the listen port is. However I do not know what the hell when it means no listening socket available means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely running another server on port 80 already. Try:

sudo lsof -i:80

.. to find out what it is.

Alternately, you could have overlapping Listen directives. Apache can't quite figure out how to merge for example "Listen 80" and Listen 192.168.1.1:80" because they're both attempting to open overlapping sockets.

Comment: Its ok, I figured it out. It is sort of embarrassing though. I download the wrong file.